# When doing IDE DMA on x86, can other CPUs access the memory?

Tags: memory, dma, x86

I am unfamiliar with hardware. I am studying the IDE disk I/O and DMA on x86. I want to know that when doing a IDE disk I/O with DMA, can other CPUs access the memory (or exactly, the same memory region as the DMA)? Of course, we assume that the OS is so stupid that it does not provides mutex in software.
I learned from wiki that there are three modes of operation, `burst mode`, `cycle stealing mode`and `transparent mode`. And I learned that it is the hardware or the software that is responsible to maintain the `cache coherence`.
So I want to know in specific with the IDE disk I/O on x86, when doing disk DMA, can other CPUs access the memory? For example a disk DMA wants to transfer data to memory region 0x10~0x30 (that is, in my opinion, the DMA starts transfer at 0x10 and will raise an interrupt when it reaches the 0x30). If now the DMA has transferred 0x10~0x20, can other CPUs modify 0x10~0x20 before the whole DMA finishes?
Thanks very much!

Comment: "Other CPU's"? What exact architecture are you thinking of? Note that "x86" is a very broad label, even if we restrict it to just the 80386 and later there's huge variety. In particular, whether the CPU's have any support for XMP.

Comment: @MSalters I mean nowadays ordinary x86 desktop architectures, which are SMP or multicore, such as the desktops we brought for family with Intel hashwell architecture.

Comment: The ordinary desktop does **not** have other CPU's.

Comment: @MSalters Oh, I didn't know this before. Then what about changing "other CPU's" to "other cores"?

Comment: In that case, the cores of a single chip share the memory bus anyway.